# How to deploy spring boot web application on tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have created spring boot web application, but I am unable to deploy spring boot web application WAR file on tomcat and I am able to run it as java application. How to run spring boot application  as web service on tomcat. I am using following code. If it is possible to run on tomcat plz help me using annotations without using web.xml and with using web.xml.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
       return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Following code for rest controller

```
@RestController
public class HelloWorld{

   @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ResponseEntity<String> get() {
       return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello World", HttpStatus.OK);
   }
}
```

Following Pom.xml I am using

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>web-service</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Comment: If I export as jar, I can't deploy in remote tomcat and unable to call this application from browser know

Comment: why should you need a separate tomcat for access application from browser.The spring boot itself contain the embedded server for that

Comment: If you still need it as a war, see my answer

Answer (score 34):

Here are two good documentations on how to deploy the `Spring Boot` App as a `war` file.

You can follow this spring boot [howto-traditional-deployment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html)  documentation -

Steps according to this documentation -

1. You update your application’s main class to extend    `SpringBootServletInitializer`.
2. The next step is to update your build configuration so that your project produces a war file rather than a jar file. `<packaging>war</packaging>`
3. Mark the embedded servlet container dependency as provided.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```

and one more way  -

See this [spring io documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications#what-about-the-java-ee-application-server) which outlines how to deploy the spring boot app to an application server.

Steps -

1. Change `jar` packaging to `war`.
2. Comment out the declaration of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` plugin in your `pom.xml`
3. Add a web entry point into your application by extending `SpringBootServletInitializer` and override the `configure` method
4. Remove the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency` and modfiy your `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency to

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
>     <exclusions>
>         <exclusion>
>             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
>         </exclusion>
>     </exclusions>
> </dependency>
> ```

In your `pom.xml`, remove `spring-beans` and `spring-webmvc` dependencies. The `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency  will include those dependecies.

Comment: I did the changes you have said, but it throwing the selection can't be run on server means it is not recognizing war.

Comment: OK. Here is another Spring Boot Traditional Deployment Documentation - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html . You can try this approach!

Comment: is there a way to make parts of the POM conditional to the lifecycle?

Comment: what benefit of war instead of jar? please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43303849/spring-boot-build-project-for-run-on-another-system-not-local-system

Answer (score 12):

Spring boot provides option to deploy the application as a traditional war file in `servlet 3.x` (**without web.xml**)supporting tomcat server.Please see [spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) for this. I will brief  what you need to do here.

**step 1** :  modify `pom.xml` to change the packaging to war:(that you already did)

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

**step 2** : change your dependency

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**step 3** :modify your war name (if you need to avoid the version details appended with the war name) in `pom.xml` under `<build>` tag.

```
<build>
    <finalName>web-service</finalName>
.....
```

**step 4** : run maven build to create war : `clean install`
step 5 : deploy the generated war file `web-service.war` in tomcat and request url in browser `http://<tomcat ip>:<tomcat port>/web-service/hello`

You should get `Hello World`.

***Note:*** Also you can remove redundant dependencies as @Ali Dehghani said.

Comment: I am getting selection cannot be run on any server.

Comment: you are running from eclipse?

Comment: Yeah. I am running in eclipse.

Comment: can you ping me your number

Answer (score 4):

Mark the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency as `provided`, like:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Note1:** Remove redundant dependencies from your `pom.xml` like:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

They are part of *spring boot starter packages*

**Note2:** Make jar not war

Comment: If I make as jar, I can't deploy on remote tomcat server  so it is not possible to call from web browser.

Comment: You could install spring boot apps as a service in linux or i guess windows and mac. All i'm saying is next time put more thought on how you're deploying your java apps (or any app, for that matter). This port binding style of app deployment has many advantages and is more aligned with today's best practices

Comment: I know sometimes we had to go this way because of some crazy corporate culture

Comment: How to use application as service. in remote tomcat server WAR file option only thing is there

Answer (score 0):

The process of converting a spring boot jar to a spring boot war is documented at: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging
Long story short, set your starter class the way you did in your example and then switch the packaging from jar to war in the .pom file. Furthermore, you need to set the spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency to provided. Once again, the process is documented in it's complete form at the link above.
Further information about this subject is available in the spring io guide, "Converting a Spring Boot JAR Application to a WAR" which is available at https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/
If i can be of any further assistance, let me know and i will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with this problem. Much of the above is good advice. My problem was to deploy on the Pivotal TC server initially.

1. Make the packaging in the pom a WAR.

   ```
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   ```
2. Add dependencies to the pom

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. I used an Application class to hold the main().
   Main had configuration code so that `EntityManager` etc could be injected. This `EntityManager` used information from the `ApplicationContext` and `persistence.xml` files for persistence information. Worked fine under SpringBoot but not under Tomcat. In fact under Tomcat the `Main()` is not called. The Application class extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`.
4. The following method is added to the Application class:

   ```
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
       Application obj = new Application();
       @SuppressWarnings("resource")
       ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml");
        applicationContext.registerShutdownHook();
        applicationContext.getBeanFactory().autowireBeanProperties(
            obj, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_NO, false);
       return application.sources(Application.class);
   }
   ```

Only the last line is required - the other code was held in `main()` before and was moved here to get injection of the `EntityManager` working.

5. The annotations needed are:

   ```
   @EnableAutoConfiguration
   @ComponentScan
   //@SpringBootApplication will consist of both of these and @Configuration
   ```
6. Some urls may now need the root context changing to include

   ```
   <artifactId>contextname</artifactId>.
   ```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

********Steps to deploy spring boot webapp** on tomcat server on local area network is as follows :-****It works 100% please try it because it is implemented by myself.**strong text

1. add the server.port = 8080 and server.address = (your pc IP address) in your project's application.properties file. **Remember:- dont put ip address inside the brackets used here just to show the ip address inside the brackets.**
2. Then make the war file of spring boot app you can make it in **eclipse** and also in **VS code** whatever IDE you are using.

**how to generate war file in vs code:-**

In the maven folder open the maven folder you will find your project
and click on the folder and there is option named clean click on clean it
will clean your project's folder named as target and after this again click
on the same project and below the clean you will find a option named install
click on that it will freshly create your folder named as target below the
src folder in your project and open this target folder you will find there
two war files one is simple and other is extension having original,from
these files you have to upload the war file other than the original file.

3. Upload the war file on tomcat server webapp folder by running the tomcat in browser and go the manager app in tomcat where you will find the option to upload the war file.
4. After this turn off your public firewall network from firewall and protection in windows security software in your system from the taskbar.
5. Go to the other computer on the same LAN and access the app url through the **http://IP_address:8080/yourwebsite_url**
   your website url will be same as your uploded war file in tomcat server.