# Build Spring project for run on another system

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, remote-server

I Successfully create a spring boot project on my own local system. I want to build a jar file so I can install it on remote server. so I had to configure server address and mySql address of remote server but I can not Build and it have many errors, and they all right cause my system can not see the remote server address and database.

this is my .properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8081/aths
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
server.address=192.168.24.250
server.port=8080
```

how can handle it for running on another configurations? ( another IP, datasource, and ...)
Am I doing it right or not? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spring profiles here :
Create different property files for different profiles using `application-{profile}.properties` format, e.g. `application-dev.properties` for dev, and `application-prod.properties` for production put your profile specific configurations in them. Then when you're running the spring boot application, activate your intended profile using the SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE environment variable or spring.profiles.active system property.

and at the end, you will run your jar file with command
`java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod application.jar`

Comment: you say that I should create two properties, for example one for my local test and one for Server?

Comment: yes @Kenji so spring will detect it by `-Dspring.profiles.active` parameter value and will load your properties, you can configure specific things for specific profile by spring profile.

Comment: example: http://www.deepzeafish.xyz/environment-specific-properties-spring-boot.html , 
here is helpfull doc:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html ,
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-definition-profiles

Comment: ok now my problem is with activating that x properties file. where i should put java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=x ?

Comment: this command need only when you need to create jar file, Basically parameter`-Dspring.profiles.active` is additional so doesn't matter you are creating jar or war just pass this parameter value with your command,
e.g : tomcat7:run -Dspring.profiles.active=prod

Answer (score 0):

You can have different `application.properties` within your resources folder and use spring profiles for example `application-{profile}.properties` and run the application with the specified profile. However this still limits the configuration items to what has been hard coded within the properties files. When running the application, if it was to be distributed to other people, where non of the profiles are supported you can provide a properties file at start up.

So in the same directory for example as the **.jar** file create a file named **application.properties** with empty place holders for all the variables required for the application so the admin can enter the details correct for them. Then they will be required to start the application with the following command

`java -jar 'applicaitonname.jar -Dspring.config.name="file:/path/to/application.properties"`

Or springboot will load properties from application.properties files in the following locations:

1. A /config subdirectory of the current directory.
2. The current directory
3. Failing that the default application.properties from the resources folder will be loaded.

Comment: so how can my app get different properties? how it get now use server properties or now use another properties? it is run time or what?

Comment: Well you can always pass another configuration file to the spring boot app when starting it with `-Dspring.config.name="file:/path/to/application.properties"`