# Tomcat 7 deployment issue for Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat7, java-7

I have created an application on spring boot using JPA and JDK 7 but I am unable to deploy this to Tomcat 7. Does tomcat 7 support Spring boot *2.0.5.RELEASE* version and the associated jar for JPA/Hibernate.

Comment: what errors do you have? could you check similar questions for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34506712/how-to-deploy-spring-boot-web-application-on-tomcat-server ?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot 2.0, requires a Servlet 3.1 container. Tomcat 7 is a Servlet 3.0 container.

So it wont work.

Comment: Any way of deploying it on tomcat??

Comment: Can we use spring with tomcat 7?? Please confirm

Comment: You mean to say that Spring and Spring boot both ain't supported by tomcat 7? How is this possible

Comment: Yes you can use spring with tomcat 7 but versions should be compatible.