# Spring Boot App deploys but won't startup in Tomcat 8

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat9

I've been working on integrating a Spring Boot Web app with Jenkins and Tomcat 9.  When I run this as a spring boot app within Eclipse, everything seems fine.

I'm now at a point where I'm setting up Jenkins and a test/qa/show-and-tell environment.  When I try to deploy the war in a standalone Tomcat9 environment, my app won't start properly.

I've followed the [spring boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) and let Eclipse do the bulk of the Tomcat integration for me.  I also used the following thread as a checklist...
[How to deploy spring boot web application on tomcat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34506712/how-to-deploy-spring-boot-web-application-on-tomcat-server)

I'm getting the same stacktrace on my dev machine as well as my target environment that has Jenkins and Tomcat 9 running as a service.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   <!--      <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>   
    </dependency>
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3305/myapp?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=*****
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
spring.messages.basename=validation

server.servlet.context-path=/

spring.jackson.serialization.wrap-root-value=false
```

**WebApplication.java**

```java
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EntityScan("com.myapp.model")
    public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements ApplicationRunner{

        private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(WebApplication.class);

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(WebApplication.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void run(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) throws Exception {
            logger.debug("Debugging log");
            logger.info("Info log");
            logger.warn("Hey, This is a warning!");
            logger.error("Oops! We have an Error. OK");
            logger.fatal("Snap! Fatal error. Please fix me.");
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

**Error log in Tomcat**

```
18-Mar-2020 18:43:38.712 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:157)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5140)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:493)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1642)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1590)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:294)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:212)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:666)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator.getCallerClass(StackLocator.java:110)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator.getCallerClass(StackLocator.java:123)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocatorUtil.getCallerClass(StackLocatorUtil.java:55)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext.getLogger(SLF4JLoggerContext.java:39)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:37)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:52)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
```

Comment: Are those your real dependencies or a dummed down version for posting? If they are the real ones your server includes an additional jar to route the logging to slf4j (or log4j2) which leads to an error because the other way around is included in the dependencies you have. Which does slf4j -> log4j2 -> slf4j -> log4j2 -> .... up until the point a stackoverflow occurs.

Comment: @M.Deinum -  Thanks for the quick response!  That's my actual POM...  I'm guessing this page: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/log4j2.html lists out the jars I need... Is there a simpler way to go about logging in my stack or should I go ahead and include the 5 jars in this guide with my maven dependencies?

Comment: The jars are already included in the starter you are using. But why aren't you just using the default logging framework, Logback? Also have you excluded that (I don't see that in your pom).

Comment: I was just following a tutorial I found... I have decided to strip out logging for now until i can get the test env up and running.  I was more familiar with log4j since I used it in the past and complicated things bringing log4j2 into the picutre...

Comment: Logback is the default and you should be using SLF4J as the logging api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a conflict with my logging jars... I commented out the maven log4j2 dependencies and switched to Logback.

Answer (score -2):

Try driver class name : 
                com.cj.mysql.jdbc.Driver